# validateSigningDebug error when I try to run the default flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile$ActionExecutionException: java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 33s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please update your question and post the result of running the `flutter doctor` command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.